# Does this getter return the reference that was given by constructor or a reference to the object inside the class? C++

Tags: c++, reference

```
class A{

    A(B& ref) : b(ref){}
    B getB(){return this->b;}
    B b;
};
```

Does getB() return a reference to A.b or the same reference that was given by the constructor?That would be a problem if the original B has been changed outside of A but A.getB() still returns the old B. 
If this would be the case, is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: A copies ref into A.b and then getB() returns another copy of that.

Comment: The question, as stated, is self-contradictory. `getB` does not return any references at all, neither to `A::b` nor to the original object given to constructor. It returns a temporary object, not a reference. For this reason the question of "which reference `getB` returns" makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, only a copy of `ref` is stored in the `b` member of the corresponding instance of `A`, and a copy of this is what's returned by `getB`.

To return the instance of `B` that the instance of `A` was initialized with (*not* what you want to do, but ffr), you would do this:

```
class A{

    A(B& ref) : b(ref){}
    B& getB(){return this->b;}
    B& b;
};
```

Comment: For example, illustrating the difference, Kylo's answer and Johnny Mopp's comment are copies of, rather than references to, this answer.  Lol couldn't resist.

Comment: J/k I realize everybody's writing things out simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

Your getter does not return a reference. To return a reference you would have to write

```
B &getB(){return this->b;}
```

Moreover b is also stored as a value not reference. So if you would like to return the same reference It should look like this:

```
class A {
  B &b;
public:
  A(B &ref) : b(ref){}
  B &getB(){return this->b;}
};
```